# Moving the chips/tags outside Autocomplete box in MUI

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I am using the MUI `Autocomplete` component and am trying to figure out if it is possible to move the chips/tags *outside* of the input box. Is this even possible? I would prefer if the chips were listed just underneath the box instead. This way the text box can be used solely for the user input and not *both* displaying the chips/tags & user input.

I have tried to play with one of the basic demo's but didn't have any luck. I cleared it back to the default state in case there are some users here that have experience with this. A starting point for an example can be the following sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-7vroo?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 13):

You can do that by disabling tag rendering inside `Autocomplete` and add your own `Chip` list below the `Autocomplete`.

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState([]);
const onDelete = (title) => () => {
  setValue((value) => value.filter((v) => v.title !== title));
};

return (
  <Box sx={{ width: 500 }}>
    <Autocomplete
      multiple
      options={top100Films}
      defaultValue={[top100Films[13]]}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      value={value}
      onChange={(e, newValue) => setValue(newValue)}
      renderTags={() => null}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} variant="outlined" placeholder="Favorites" />
      )}
    />
    <Box
      mt={3}
      sx={{
        '& > :not(:last-child)': { marginRight: 1 },
        '& > *': { marginBottom: 1 },
      }}
    >
      {value.map((v) => (
        <Chip key={v.title} label={v.title} onDelete={onDelete(v.title)} />
      ))}
    </Box>
  </Box>
);
```

```js
const top100Films = [
  { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
]
```

### Live Demo

##### V5

[image: Edit 66881433/moving-the-chips-tags-out-of-the-autocomplete-box-in-material-ui (forked)]

##### V4

[image: Edit 66881433/moving-the-chips-tags-out-of-the-autocomplete-box-in-material-ui]

Comment: Default option is not selected in option list, Also in code `defaultValue={[top100Films[1]]}` but that chips is not rendered